# Issues in running ipython notebook on Windows Xp

Tags: python, sockets

I have a 32 bit WinXP system that used to run ipython notebook just fine under the Miniconda distribution (Python  3.4). But recently, when I start the ipython notebook interface in the browser I get a kernel error. The console shows a ZMQError. However, I have no issue working from the ipython console or even from inside PyCharm IDE, where python works fine. I am using a virtual environment, and the details about the error are given below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Miniconda3\envs\mltestbed\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 436, in wrapper
    result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
  File "F:\Miniconda3\envs\mltestbed\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 56, in post
    model = sm.create_session(path=path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "F:\Miniconda3\envs\mltestbed\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 66, in create_session
    kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "F:\Miniconda3\envs\mltestbed\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 84, in start_kernel
    **kwargs)
  File "F:\Miniconda3\envs\mltestbed\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 109, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "F:\Miniconda3\envs\mltestbed\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 241, in start_kernel
    self._connect_control_socket()
  File "F:\Miniconda3\envs\mltestbed\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 192, in _connect_control_socket
    self._control_socket = self.connect_control()
  File "F:\Miniconda3\envs\mltestbed\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 445, in connect_control
    return self._create_connected_socket('control', identity=identity)
  File "F:\Miniconda3\envs\mltestbed\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 417, in _create_connected_socket
    sock = self.context.socket(socket_type)
  File "F:\Miniconda3\envs\mltestbed\lib\site-packages\zmq\sugar\context.py", line 143, in socket
    s = self._socket_class(self, socket_type)
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 281, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.__cinit__ (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:3220)
zmq.error.ZMQError: Connection refused
```

In need of help as my system contains a lot of code that would be difficult to port.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps you, but there seems to be a similar error experienced by some [spyder users](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/1880). This goes back to a problem in binding to a random port for the notebook server using ZeroMQ (see [here](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/pull/651)). The bug in question seems to be fixed in ZeroMQ, but I am not sure if it has made it's way to the other packages you are using.

You could try to update the version of ipython-notebook you are using:

```
$ conda update ipython-notebook
```

and if this doesn't work you could fall back to an older version. Try creating a new environment with an older version to keep your (hopefully soon repaired) environment intact:

```
$ conda create -n fallback ipython-notebook=3 python=3.4
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, but that does not help. Issue persists and ipython notebooks give the same error as quoted in the original post. I also get a Windows error to the effect "python.exe - Application error" The exception software exception (0x40000015) occurred in the application at the location 0x7c812fd3

Comment: A similar issue, as mentioned in the tracker, could be caused by an anti-virus or firewall software. Have you recently changed your setup in that regard?

Comment: None whatsoever. I just tried uninstalling everything and doing a fresh miniconda install. But the issue has persisted.

Comment: This is strange. I'm afraid I can not reproduce your error :( Could you try to run notebook using `ipython notebook --debug`? Maybe this sheds some light on what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: I now get an error on the console that says : "ZMQError Connection .refused." Assertion failed: Socket operation on non -socket (bundled\zeromq\src\signaler.cpp:181 ).

Comment: As you might already have guessed I am am out of ideas :( Sorry I could not help you.